# Json array modification

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I try to generate Donut chart code using Json array. I have stuck with in one place

This is my code

```
<?php 
  $canvas_data = array(
    
    'type' => 'doughnut',
    'data' => array(
      'labels' => array(),  // this array will be populated from the repeater
      'datasets' => array(
        'label' => '',
        'backgroundColor' => array('#4e73df', '#1cc88a','#36b9cc','#df4e75'),
        'borderColor'=> array('#ffffff','#ffffff','#ffffff','#ffffff'),
        'data' => array() // this array will be populated from the repeater
      )
    ),
    'options' => array(
      'maintainAspectRatio' => false,
      'legend' => array(
        'display' => false,
      ),
      'title' => array()
    ),
  );
  // loop over repeater and populate object
  if (have_rows('donut_graph_details')) {
    while (have_rows('donut_graph_details')) {
      the_row();
      $canvas_data['data']['labels'][] = get_sub_field('title');
      $canvas_data['data']['datasets']['data'][] = get_sub_field('percentage');
    }
  }
  // use json encode to output attribute
?>
<canvas data-bs-chart='<?php echo json_encode($canvas_data); ?>'></canvas>
```

Out put using this code

```
<canvas data-bs-chart='{"type":"doughnut","data":{"labels":["IMPLEMENTED","PARTIALLY IMPLEMENTED","NOT IMPLEMENTED","UNDISCLOSED"],"datasets":{"label":"","backgroundColor":["#4e73df","#1cc88a","#36b9cc","#df4e75"],"borderColor":["#ffffff","#ffffff","#ffffff","#ffffff"],"data":["40","30","10","20"]}},"options":{"maintainAspectRatio":false,"legend":{"display":false},"title":[]}}'></canvas>
```

But I want to do small modification to the Out put. I want to add "[" before starting "datasets" and wants to close it . I have add the modification code below.

```
<canvas data-bs-chart='{"type":"doughnut","data":{"labels":["IMPLEMENTED","PARTIALLY IMPLEMENTED","NOT IMPLEMENTED","UNDISCLOSED"],"datasets":[{"label":"","backgroundColor":["#4e73df","#1cc88a","#36b9cc","#df4e75"],"borderColor":["#ffffff","#ffffff","#ffffff","#ffffff"],"data":["40","30","10","20"]}]},"options":{"maintainAspectRatio":false,"legend":{"display":false},"title":[]}}'></canvas>
```

Comment: So wrap the content of `datasets` into another array then.

Comment: @CBroe I try that one also but not working . This is the out put whan adding another array. '<canvas data-bs-chart='{"type":"doughnut","data":{"labels":["IMPLEMENTED","PARTIALLY IMPLEMENTED","NOT IMPLEMENTED","UNDISCLOSED"],"datasets":{"0":{"label":"","backgroundColor":["#4e73df","#1cc88a","#36b9cc","#df4e75"],"borderColor":["#ffffff","#ffffff","#ffffff","#ffffff"],"data":[]},"data":["40","30","10","20"]}},"options":{"maintainAspectRatio":false,"legend":{"display":false},"title":[]}}'></canvas>

Comment: You must have added it wrong, right now your `datasets` contains one array under the index `0`, and another element under the key `data`. Of course you don't get `[...]` in your result then, because JavaScript does not know associative arrays, so this must become an object at this point.

Comment: You probably neglected to modify what you are doing inside the `while` loop accordingly ...?